# In pandas, how to convert a column of float32 values to float16 values?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management

I have a pandas column of float32 numbers, I would like to convert them to float16 to save memory.

I tried looking "pandas convert column of float32 to float16" but most of my results were mostly about numpy.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1.456, 53.2368]})
print (df)
       col
0   1.4560
1  53.2368

df['col'] = df['col'].astype(np.float16)
```

Or:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('float16')
```

---

```
print (df.dtypes)
col    float16
dtype: object
```